# Multiple object detection on android using OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface, object-detection

I'm trying to develop an application that detects certain objects such as people, vehicles and trees. As a start I tried to port the [OpenCV pedestrian sample](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/peopledetect.cpp) but I get a very low frame rate with a lot of false positives.

I may have made incorrect interpretations and costly computations since I'm just starting OpenCV and don't understand C++ much either.

```
@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    Mat frame = inputFrame.rgba();

    float minScale = 0.4f, maxScale = 5;    /* minimum and maximum scale to detect */
    int totalScales = 55;                   /* preferred number of scales between min and max */
    int threshold = -1;                     /* detections with score less then threshold will be ignored */

    HOGDescriptor hog = new HOGDescriptor();
    hog.setSVMDetector(HOGDescriptor.getDefaultPeopleDetector());

    MatOfRect foundLocations = new MatOfRect();
    MatOfDouble foundWeights = new MatOfDouble();

    Mat tempMat = new Mat(frame.rows(), frame.cols(), CvType.CV_8UC3);
    Imgproc.cvtColor(frame, tempMat, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB);

    hog.detectMultiScale(tempMat, foundLocations, foundWeights, 1.5, new Size(8,8),
            new Size(32, 32), 1.05, 2, false);

    Vector<Rect> foundLocationsFilteredList = new Vector<Rect>();
    filterRects(foundLocations.toList(), foundLocationsFilteredList);

    for (Rect foundLocation : foundLocationsFilteredList) {
        Core.rectangle(frame, foundLocation.tl(), foundLocation.br(), new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 3);
    }

    tempMat.release();
    return frame;
}

private final void filterRects(List<Rect> candidates, List<Rect> objects) {
    for (int i = 0; i < candidates.size(); ++i) {
        Rect r = candidates.get(i);

        int j;
        for (j = 0; j < candidates.size(); ++j) {
            if (j != i && r.equals(candidates.get(j)))
                break;
        }

        if (j == candidates.size())
            objects.add(r);
    }
}
```

- Would the frame processing be faster if done using JNI? Or would it be better to go for a different approach?
- How should I proceed for multiple object detection

Comment: How long is a piece of string?  Without doubt your code will run faster if implemented in C++ and executed using JNI. However, just how much faster will depend on lots of information you haven't given us - for instance, the size of `foundLocations`.  I believe that the OpenCV docs recommend that you implement any non-trivial algorithm in C++,

Comment: @Marko It's slow even with C++. I guess running the descriptor on every frame is bound to make things slow.

Comment: Yes - doing this on every frame is probably optimistic.  Are you making use of all of CPU cores of the device you run this on, and have you got the optimal compiler flags?  By default you won't get NEON optimisations for ARM v7a parts.

Answer (score 0):

JNI definitely accelerates the process. And there's a JNI example in OpenCV4Android bundle. I've written some programs on Android using OpenCV and JNI just works great for me. It's a face detection example. Replace the detector with your own object detector.

For various detectors, detecting multiple or single object is specified in the parameters. Go to the document. Most of the time, the detector returns multiple results by default.

### Edit

Here's an example of JNI using OpenCV. The original tracker is in C++ and I adapted it to Android. Welcome fork.

[Link to Project](https://github.com/SolessChong/android-aam)

Comment: The detectors that I could find only target a specific object. I believe using more detectors on the same frame is only gonna make things slower?

Comment: What do you mean by "more detectors"?

Comment: I mean separate detectors for people, vehicles and other objects that I want to detect.

Comment: Exactly. You have to combine these different detectors in a deep level. Perhaps with different models but same algorithm.

Comment: Try using Bag of Words approach instead of a classifier which is meant to detect a single class of object. Use HOG combned with BOW.